# click anywhere in wordpress site it redirect me to wrong url

Tags: wordpress

In my wordpress site on load of site when i click on any where in the page it redirect me to wrong url `http://findbetterresults.com/?dn=wpspamhammer.com&pid=9PO755G95`

Comment: http://www.icanwinsports.com/basketball/ and this is my site url

Comment: you have probably installed some malicious plugin. Try removing them one by one.

Comment: i already deactivate my installed plugin but no change.please give me solution

Answer (score 0):

seems this script included in your code.

http://services.wpspamhammer.com/js/client/request.min.js

remove this script and try.

Comment: there is no script in my folder like request.min.js.

Comment: seems your site not loading now. I saw the code in your site

Comment: http://www.keepbrowsersafe.com/remove-findbetterresults-com-windows-system-easy-steps

Comment: i currently working on it so it seems like forbidden error